# How to evaluate  performance of a Java EE application?

Tags: performance, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

There can be many ways to do one task (example: to view some thing on jsp, JSTL or scriplets can be used some other classes or our own custom tag library ).

But the speed, performance, memory usage of the JSP page runs can be different. I believe that if the performance, the speed, time usage (when a JSP page or servlet is called) can be calculated or evaluated, the best way can be chosen among other ways. I wish to have a solution for Java EE applications(jsp servelts, struts, spring, ejb, ..).(not to see the server performance)

So any one let me know that a way to find those if it is possible. Any tutorial,link welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the performance of entire application running you can always make use of profilers. You can use **JVisualVM** that comes with jdk installation or you can use any one of he third party profilers available in market like **JProfiler** and **YourKit**. Among these YourKit has very nice features. But both JProfiler and YourKit are paid versions.

And if you need to check performance for executing a particular piece of code in your Spring application then you can make use of **StopWatch** class available in Spring utils package. It gives you the output in a very nice formated way. It gives you the time used by a piece of code to execute. [Here](http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/Spring_Timer) is an example of the same.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Japs. I use NetBeans IDE and tried its profiler. For Java SE applications it works well.But when I tried with JSP Servlet application, the app doesn't work. I ll take a look at your profilers. (happy if there are free)

Comment: As I said you JVisualVM is only free version that comes with JDK itself. But you can also checkout the trial versions of JProfiler and Yourkit. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it really helped you. :-)

Comment: Will you let me know, is there are big difference between JVisualVM and other third party paid profilers?

Comment: Not very big difference. All works like same. But generally java develpers prefer YourKit. Its GUI and reports are good. But if you don't want the profiler for a big reason or its much much required for you then and only then go for the paid versions. Otherwise its ok to use JVisulaVM for small time. :-)